# Usage of like in Specification is not working in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, specifications

I have in my db a Plan with a name
"New Plan" but everytime I query with the parameter "New", it won't give me the results. (Which it should return since I'm using `like`)

Is there something wrong on how I constructed my Specification?
Thank you

Specification:

```
public Specification<Plan> hasOptionalName(String name) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> name == null ?
                criteriaBuilder.conjunction() :
                criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), name);
    }
```

```
public Specification<Plan> buildSpecification(Long id, String name, PlanStatus status) {
    return planSpecification.withId(id)
            .and(planSpecification.withStatus(status))
            .and(planSpecification.hasOptionalName(name));
}
```

But the results won't return "New Plan" but when I remove the filter, it will be returned.

Comment: are you sure that `id` and `status` you are providing matches this record with `name` equals *New Plan*?

Comment: @m.antkowicz yes sir. because when I remove the name filter, the `New Plan` will be returned (still with the id and status filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`criteriaBuilder.like()` doenst put the `%` for you, so wath your are doing there is looking for a plan that is call `New`(exactly is this case) you should add the `%` on the string you are looking for, something like that:

`criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + name + "%")`

Examples of like with criteriaBuilder: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string

Comment: thank you sir! :D i thought it's not anymore needed. thank you once again!